# Implementing Double-Jump Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

Hi I am trying to implement a double jump using javascript and phaser 3 library but it wont work and i cant figure out why.I have declared this.canDoubleJump as true in create(),  Here is the code to my update function.

```
        const didPressJump = this.cursors.space.isDown;

        if (didPressJump) {
            if (this.player.body.onFloor()) {
                this.canDoubleJump = true;
                this.player.play('pablo_jump', true);
                this.player.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            } else if (this.canDoubleJump) {
                this.canDoubleJump = false;
                this.player.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

```
        let justPressedJump = this.cursors.space.isDown;
        
        if (!justPressedJump && this.player.body.onFloor()) {
            this.player.allowedToJump = true;
        }
        
        if (justPressedJump && this.player.body.onFloor() && this.player.allowedToJump) {
           
            this.canDoubleJump = true;
            this.player.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            this.player.allowedToJump = false;
        }
        else if(this.canDoubleJump){
            console.log(this.canDoubleJump)
            this.player.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            this.canDoubleJump = false;
        }
```

SOLUTION:

```
        const didPressJump =Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.cursors.space);

        if (didPressJump) {
          if (this.player.body.onFloor()) {
            this.canDoubleJump = true;
            this.player.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            this.player.play('pablo_jump', true)
          } else if (this.canDoubleJump) {
            this.canDoubleJump = false;
            this.player.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            this.player.play('pablo_double_jump', true)
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work:

1. The user presses space bar, e.g. for 0.3 seconds
2. `didPressJump` is true, `this.player.body.onFloor()` is true. Player jumps
3. After one frame, e.g. 1/30 = 0.0333 seconds, `didPressJump` is still true but `this.player.body.onFloor()` is false. Player double jumps in the very next frame.

Solution:

Double jump can only be triggered after user released space bar.

There is also another "bug". When the player is falling (`!this.player.body.onFloor()`)) but didn't jump before, double jump is not possible. But if player jumps, lands on the floor and then is falling, a double jump is possible.

Comment: Thanks I understand why its not working now Im just trying to find a different way to test the input. If i use onDown or onUp he just jumps over and over. Cant find any onrelease or anything in the docs...

Comment: @BenMarr If there is no `onrelease` you can create your own `onrelease`. Store the previous state of `didPressJump` and compare it with the current state.

Comment: @BenMarr I think you should ask a new question. My answer answers your initial question. Another answer could answer your edit and this becomes confusing.

Comment: It answers the question but i still cant get the double jump to work. I will post a solution if i find it